# number with finite binary representation and infinite decimal representation

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

One can easily find numbers with finite decimal representation with infinite binary representation. (Like $0.3$ and $0.01010101..$)

I assume there is an opposite case, meaning a number with finite binary representation but infinite decimal representation, does any of you know such number? if the existence is impossible then why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It’s impossible.

A number has a finite binary representation if and only if it can be written as a fraction whose denominator is a power of $2$: $\dfrac{k}{2^n}$ for some integer $k$ and some non-negative integer $n$.

A number has a finite decimal representation if and only if it can be written in the form $\dfrac{k}{2^m5^n}$ for some integer $k$ and non-negative integers $m$ and $n$.

Clearly the first is a special case of the second.

Comment: Clear, to the point, and correct.  +1

Answer (score 9):

Well, one can be a wiseguy:

$$0.1_2=0.5_{10}=0.49999....$$

**Any** finite decimal expansion can be made infinite...

Comment: I like that.  +1

Answer (score 2):

If a number, $q$, has a finite binary expansion, that means that
$$
q=\frac p{2^n}
$$
for some integers $p$ and $n$.  Since $\frac12=\frac5{10}$, we have that $q=\dfrac p{2^n}=\dfrac{5^np}{10^n}$ also has a finite decimal expansion.