# Infinite binary having infinite decimal

Tags: infinity, decimal-expansion

Can a finite decimal has an infinite binary representation? I have come to a conclusion that it may not be possible based on what I have read from the following:

What cannot happen is that the decimal is infinite and the binary is finite.

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-some-binary-numbers-have-infinite-digits-after-the-point-or-will-they-ever-end-for-example-decimal-0-1-to-binary

[Comparing infinite binary fractions to infinite decimal fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452155/comparing-infinite-binary-fractions-to-infinite-decimal-fractions)

[number with finite binary representation and infinite decimal representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261988/number-with-finite-binary-representation-and-infinite-decimal-representation)

Am I right or wrong. Any reasons or proofs to facilitate the comprehension will be helpful

Comment: How did you get to this conclusion from the links? It's incorrect.

Comment: @DonThousand Never trust Quora for maths questions...

Comment: This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear. I don't know why the question should be closed. Please can anyone vote to open the question?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac13$ – and more generally any unit fraction $\frac1n$ where $n$ contains some prime factor other than $2$ or $5$ – is non-terminating in both binary and decimal.

Comment: But 0.2 is finite decimal right? I mean infinite binary $\implies$ infinite decimal (i.e., repeating decimal).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: As I read the question, the claim is that there is no number that has no terminating binary expansion and no terminating decimal expansion.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{1}{2} = .5 = (.1)_2$$
$$\frac{1}{3} = .333\ldots = (.010101\ldots)_2$$
$$\frac{1}{5} = .2 = (.001100110011\ldots)_2$$

So it can happen that

- both expansions are finite
- both are infinite
- the decimal is finite and the binary is infinite.

What cannot happen is that the decimal is infinite and the binary is finite.
May be that's what you are trying to prove.

In other words we have the implication:

- Decimal infinite $\Rightarrow$ binary infinite.

Or equivalently

- Binary finite $\Rightarrow$ decimal finite.

To prove this observe that if $x = (.b_1b_2\ldots b_n)_2$ then
$$x = \frac{m}{2^n} = \frac{m\, 5^n}{10^n}$$ which has a finite decimal expansion.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac13=0.010101\ldots_{\text{two}}=0.333\ldots_{\text{ten}}$$